# Ностальгия: тоска по родине или по прошлому?

Tags: значение-слов

В одних случаях ностальгией называют конкретно тоску по родине, но часто слышу ее и в значении "тоска по прошлому". Так все-таки, что такое ностальгия?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В современном понимании и то, и другое. Изначально ностальгия - это болезненная тоска по родине, но сейчас под ностальгией понимают грусть по тому, что уже не вернуть, и прошлое в этом отношении, гораздо большая потеря, чем покинутая отчизна.

Comment: А грамотно ли называть ностальгией тоску по прошлому?

Comment: Я почитала статью про возникновение понятия "ностальгия" (она сначала считалась болезнью). Так там сплошь и рядом о прошлом, и ничего - про родину.  
Если задуматься, человек, уехав навсегда из своей страны вспоминает именно *свою прошлую жизнь там*, а не думает о том, какова эта страна сейчас.

Answer (score 1):

Я не понимаю, в чем тут сложность. Для ответов на эти вопросы есть толковые словари.

Ожегов:

> > НОСТАЛЬГИЯ, -и, ж. (книжн.). Тоска по родине, а также вообще тоска попрошлому. II прил. ностальгический, -ая, -ое. Ностальгические нотки.

Большая сов. энциклопедия:

> > тоска по родине; тоска по чему-нибудь утраченному, ушедшему.